# how to retrieve google Oauth token by doing a post request in nodejs?

Tags: javascript, node.js, oauth-2.0, google-oauth

I've been trying to retrieve access token by going through this procedure:

https://developers.google.com/accounts/docs/OAuth2WebServer

But everytime I use this: https://github.com/google/google-api-nodejs-client/ 
I get a redirect_uri_mismatch error.

If I try via Firefox Poster, I still get the same error: redirect_uri_mismatch

I've checked multiple times that my redirect_uri at the Web Client Id that I created and the one that I'm sending via Poster is this: `http://localhost/callback`

I'm at the endof my wits as I'm not sure what I'm doing wrong.